# LibXML2 stripping new lines inside attribute

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, libxml2

I'm working in an iOS application which uses libXML2 to read XML retrieved from a backend system.  I have the following XML, which is part of a larger XML document:

```xml
<properties uiValue="This is a multiline description with text that should wrap but should also preserve any whitespace:                         like this whitespace.

And preserve newlines.

espace:~` !@#$%^&amp;*()_+=-&lt;&gt;/  \" name="desc">
            <values value="This is a multiline description with text that should wrap but should also preserve any whitespace:                         like this whitespace.

And preserve newlines.

espace:~` !@#$%^&amp;*()_+=-&lt;&gt;/  \"/>
</properties>
```

As a whole, the document seems to parse OK.  The problem that I have is that the newlines are not being processed, so when I read the attribute value, the result is:

```
This is a multiline description with text that should wrap but should also preserve any whitespace:                         like this whitespace.    And preserve newlines.    espace:~` !@#$%^&amp;*()_+=-&lt;&gt;/
```

Is there any way to keep these new lines?  If I print out the response XML from the server directly, the new lines are preserved.  When I go through the parsing though, the new lines are stripped out.  To complicate matters a bit, this is some third party code that I'm trying to fix, and I haven't really used libXML2 that much.  The relevant code (I believe) is:

```cpp
NSLog(@"Response:\n%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);

xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory([data bytes], [data length], NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_COMPACT | XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

xmlNodePtr cur = ....;
xmlChar *attrValue = xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar *) "uiValue");
NSString *attrString = [NSString stringWithCString:(char*)attrValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I have tried taking the XML_PARSE_COMPACT and XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS options out, but that didn't help (not that I expected it to, I believe those only affect nodes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Parsers cannot and will not preserve linebreaks in attributes.  From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#AVNormalize):

> Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or
>   checked for validity, the XML processor MUST normalize the attribute
>   value by applying the algorithm below:
>
> - All line breaks must have been normalized on input to #xA as described in 2.11 End-of-Line Handling, so the rest of this algorithm operates on text normalized in this way.
> - ...
> - For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value.

The library performs this normalization as it's parsing, so the newlines are gone.  You can escape your newlines with numeric entity references as `&#xA;` but usually if you need to depend on the linebreaks, element values are used.

```
<properties uiValue="This is a multiline description with text that should wrap but &#xA;should also preserve any whitespace:                         like this whitespace.&#xA;&#xA;    And preserve newlines.&#xA;&#xA;    espace:~` !@#$%^&amp;*()_+=&#xA;&lt;&gt;/  ">
    <value>This is a multiline description with text that should wrap but should also preserve any whitespace:                         like this whitespace.

And preserve newlines.

espace:~` !@#$%^&amp;*()_+=-&lt;&gt;/  "</value>
</properties>
```